# Better 'inbox' behaviour

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, notifications, global-inbox

I don't know whether this has been raised before, but I can't find a question on it so I'm raising it here.

I think there should least be a configurable option to change the behavior of the Stack Exchange inbox.  I like that I'm told that I have (say) 4 new 'notifications' waiting for me, but I have 2 issues with the behavior.

1. When I click on the Stack Exchange dropdown and go to inbox, those 4 new 'notifications' are not highlighted.  Am I just to assume that the 4 most recent are the new ones?  It would be very convenient if they were highlighted.
2. When I click on one of the links and go to a reply or something, suddenly my 'new notifications' drops to zero.  I only visited one of the notifications... I still want to know what the other 3 were!  Argh.  Could we have it so that the new ones are highlighted, and when I click one, it becomes un-highlighted, but doesn't mark all new notifications as if they had been read?

Comment: #1 is now [meta-tag:status-completed]: new items have a different background color. (By the way, they are usually the top ones, but not always, because chat notifications are inserted after a delay.) For #2, I'm voting to close as a duplicate of a more recent, and more detailed, very similar request.