# Make recent inbox messages, keep single messages track

Tags: feature-request, notifications, top-bar

Today I got 7 messages, unfortunately after I looked to see what I got, it marked them all as seen.

Can you change it, so when I review one message it will not mark all the rest as seen? It's hard to remember each time what is new and what is not.

Comment: There's a timestamp next to each message.  Doesn't that help?

Comment: No, because than I need to remember what time I got the last message, and also keep time track while I review my other messages, so I will remember that the last message is 4 hours and two minutes ago.

Comment: Hi Gilles, I edit the question. Now it is different as it does not suggest a solution but only points the problem. Let SE to design.

Comment: @Gilles also it is pointless to mark a question as duplicated if the duplicated question does not have an answer. It just not helping...

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman Feature requests or bug reports don't need to be answered to be suitable duplicates. It helps not to have the same thing requested multiple times in different posts.

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman It's absolutely not pointless to mark duplicates as duplicates, even when they aren't answered. If someone answered MDeSchaepmeester's question while you weren't aware of it, you'd never get the answer you were seeking.