# Mark read notifications as unread

Tags: feature-request, android-app, notifications, global-inbox

In the Android app, can we have some option to mark a read notification to unread?
I know that this option is not available in the web version of Stack Exchange sites. But sometimes I open the notification in the app and it opens the post, but sometimes I can't see the exact reply to my comment or where my name is mentioned using the app.

And I want those comments to be read from the web version of the Stack Exchange site. Sometimes I forget about replying to a comment since the notification is already marked as read. So I want to mark the notification as unread and have it as a new notification displayed in the mobile app and the web version too.

Comment: I came across this post while looking through requests related to the inbox... Since the app's no longer supported, I've closed this request as "no longer reproducible". (That said, the same request could apply to the regular web version, but there are already several other feature requests on MSE related to that.)

Answer (score 6):

I think this feature request applies as much to the web version as the mobile apps. If you don't have the time to reply or post something, you will have to remind yourself of doing that if you read the comment.

With that in mind, your request is very close to [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234940/245360) that proposed a 'only mark as read if I said so'. (so that proposal is the other way around, and specific to the web version)

Is it useful? I guess so. Are there drawbacks? Well, it may clutter UI and go beyond the volatile nature of comments. That remark doesn't go up for other events in your inbox.

I would love to see this feature, but I hope it can be made in such way it doesn't take too much 'maintenance' from the user (just an occasional click if you really want to be remembered of it).

Comment: I think of long pressing the notification in the mobile app should display "Mark as unread" and that should rollback to it previous state(unread). And in the webversion it would be easy to have a small icon to mark the notification as actually read.

Comment: Why does it go beyond the volatile nature of comments? I don't get this bit

Answer (score -1):

I don't have an Android device at hand so I don't know if in the Android version there is a share feature or not. If it has, then you may share the comment to a to-do app like Todoist to have it reminded you later.