# Mark Notification As Unread

Tags: feature-request, android-app, notifications, ios-app

Please add a *unread* option for notifications.
It should, if possible

- Sync between App and site.
- Be available on iOS, Android (Windows too? Let's be altruistic).
- Have a "mark *all* as read" option, too.

Comment: Related / duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261554/245360.

Comment: For the above post: this feature isn't implemented on the normal site, so as far as I am concerned, it should be added there first, then to the apps.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I'm asking it be added to both.

Comment: You only added the [tag:ios-app] tag. And the duplicate has an answer that points to such a feature.

Comment: I added no tag. It was automatic.

Comment: Can't find a website tag that fits.

Comment: That is an interesting one. You are right.

Comment: The "duplicate" no answer, just a comment posted as an answer.

Comment: It is the same feature requested.

Comment: Can we do as asked at the end of question here, I.E. Unite to a single question so we can follow this? Thanks!

Comment: They *are* united into a single question -- that's what closing as a duplicate does. We don't normally delete duplicate feature requests (or duplicate questions in general), since they may contain useful additional details or search keywords that the main request lacks. We just add a banner directing viewers to the main request, and close the duplicate(s) so that answers won't be spread across multiple questions.

Comment: (The "already has an answer" part of the dupe banner is, admittedly, somewhat misleading here on meta. This question, like the one it has been closed as a duplicate of, is a feature request; as such, it cannot be *really* answered until and unless the feature is either implemented, or definitively declined. Since that hasn't happened yet, the request will just have to remain open for now. Still, there's no point in having several essentially identical requests active, so closing all but one of them is reasonable.)

Comment: Ok. In that case may I suggest it be edited to be more clear? Thanks.